# Menu with sub-items from channel entries

Tags: channel-entries

I have a channel called services. The entries from that channel are used to populate a dropdown menu & a sidebar menu.

The problem is that there are some services that have sub-services.

I need to display only the parent services in the dropdown menu but need to display the parents with their children in the sidebar menu.

How can I do this when all services are in the same channel and there are no categories to create a nested list of parents & children services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I needed to have a certain set of entries available on a dropdown (vs all on the sub-nav), I did this by adding another field to the channel.  So say you add a field (P&T Pill?) for "Entry Type" ("cf_services_entry_type").  You have two options:  Parent / Child.  Then you can filter your entries based on those options.  So your main menu would be

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="services" search:cf_services_entry_type="parent" dynamic="no}
```

Creating the sub-menu would be a little trickier because your entries don't know who their parent is (or do you have a field set up for that?)  So Yuri's suggestion of using a relationship field would probably be necessary to accomplish this.

Comment: It looks like a combination of the related entry & assigning each entry either as a parent or a child with another custom field did the trick. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com/) add-on.

Option 2: keep submenus within "root level" entries (e.g. using Relationship field)